# How to set/trigger email alert using AlertManager of prometheus

Tags: grafana, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, grafana-alerts

How to set/trigger email alert using Alert-Manager of Prometheus

What parameters needs to set for email alert of Alert-Manager of Prometheus and

where and which files to set/configure

Answer (score 0):

There you go: https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/configuration/

Click around the website for the [Prometheus end of the configuration](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/), including [how to set up an alert](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/).